# Функция decompose() в BS4

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Всем привет ! У меня такой вопрос,как сделать срез спарщенных данных?
Я парсю даты 10 новостных ресурсов,и вот при парсенге одного из ресурсов у меня траблы.

Когда я парсю дату [этого ресурса](https://www.inform.kz/ru/kasym-zhomart-tokaev-gosudarstvo-prodolzhit-okazyvat-podderzhku-kul-ture_a3558745) дата при парсинге выходят таким образом: [image: рсинг]
Я бы хотел чтобы дата была такая **23 августа 2019 10:25**

Чтобы это исправить я решил использовать функцию BS4 `decompose()`.
Код:

```
def get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page,'lxml')
    item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
    if item_datetime is not None:
        item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]}).text
        item_datetime = item_datetime.span.decompose()
        print(item_datetime)
    else:
        if (len(datetime1_rule) == 3):
            item_datetime = soup.find(datetime1_rule[0],{datetime1_rule[1]:datetime1_rule[2]})
            item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
        else:
            item_datetime = ''
    return item_datetime
```

На выводе такая ошибка:

> File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/sql_parser.py",
>   line 35, in get_item_datetime
>       item_datetime = item_datetime.span.decompose() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'span'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Как решить?

**UPD**

```
# < Собираем даты с страницы.
def get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page,'lxml')
    item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
    if item_datetime is not None:
        item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]}).text
        item_datetime_node = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
        item_datetime = item_datetime_node.text
        item_datetime_node.span.decompose() 
        print(item_datetime)
    else:
        if (len(datetime1_rule) == 3):
            item_datetime = soup.find(datetime1_rule[0],{datetime1_rule[1]:datetime1_rule[2]})
            item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
        else:
            item_datetime = ''
    return item_datetime
```

Comment: 1. Что конкретно вы хотите получить?
2. Вам в тексте ошибки английским по белому написали, что ваш объект - строка. 
3. ... а если бы вы почитали документацию по `bs4 decompose()`, вы бы увидели там, что этот метод работает с `tree`.
4. неужели самому тяжело провести небольшое исследование проблемы вместо того, чтобы сразу задавать вопрос на SO?

Comment: 1.Я дополнил что я хотел бы получить.

Comment: `item_datetime.span.decompose()` не сработает, т.к. выше вы в `item_datetime` положили строковой объект: `item_datetime = soup.find ... .text`. Нужно использовать несколько переменных: `item_datetime_node = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})` `item_datetime = item_datetime_node.text` и `item_datetime_node.span.decompose()`

Comment: @gil9red можете оформить ваш комментарий как ответ ?

Comment: @strawdog,  вы не правы, `decompose` работает с элементами

Comment: @Raharasomaha, ок, сейчас :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение `item_datetime.span.decompose()` не сработает, т.к. выше вы в `item_datetime` положили строковой объект:

```
item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]}).text
```

Нужно использовать несколько переменных:

```
item_datetime_node = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
item_datetime = item_datetime_node.text
item_datetime_node.span.decompose()
```

---

**PS.**

Метод [decompose](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) возвращает `None`, поэтому выражение ниже уберет значение из `item_datetime`:

```
item_datetime = item_datetime.span.decompose()
```

---

**UPD.**

Допустим, тут вы парсите строку в дату:

```
item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime)
```

Переменная `item_datetime` будет хранить объект `datetime`. Теперь нужно будет ее привести к строке, для этого используйте метод `strftime`, чтобы получить дату вида `23 августа 2019 10:25`:

```
item_datetime_str = item_datetime.strftime('%d %B %Y %H:%M')
```

Минипример тестирования конвертации `datetime` в строку:

```
import datetime as DT
print(DT.datetime.now().strftime('%d %B %Y %H:%M'))  # 23 August 2019 14:03
```

Значение `strftime` зависит от текущей локали системы (у меня на английском, поэтому `August`, а не `август`)

Comment: Все хорошо было бы.Но полученную дату `dateparser` не понимает

Comment: @Raharasomaha, ваш вопрос касался `.decompose() `, а ветка кода с dateparser с ним не пересекается. И как я писал в предыдущем ответе, вы уверены, что там дата, что вы *парсите*, формата `'%d %B %Y %H'`? Если вы хотите вывести дату как `%d %B %Y %H`, тогда сначала парсите ее строку, чтобы получить объект даты -- datetime (или date), а после этого приводите его к строке

Comment: окей,вас понял ! Благодарю вас за все !